# Como importar dados firebird para mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, firebird

Como importar dados do *Firebird* para *Mysql* usando o `PHP`?

Comment: Esta pergunta foi fechada como "ampla demais" sem que o autor tivesse chance de postar sua resposta (que originalmente havia sido postada na área de perguntas; o autor ficou de arrumar conforme minha orientação). Por isso reabri e postei a resposta dele. Não vejo como ampla demais, considerando a resposta curta abaixo.

Answer (score 3):

> A resposta abaixo havia sido originalmente postada como pergunta, pelo próprio autor da pergunta. Posto agora como Wiki da Comunidade para registrar.

Há um tempo atrás tive a necessidade de importar os dados de uma tabela do firebird para outra tabela no mysql, na ocasião não achei nada pronto que atendesse às necessidades então pesquisei e montei o código abaixo.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);//zera o limite de tempo

//conexão com mysql
$mysql=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');

//conexão com firebird
$ibase=ibase_connect('C:\RAAS.GDB', 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey') or die ('Erro ao conectar');
$i=0;


$busca=ibase_query("SELECT CD_COD, CD_DESCR FROM S_CID",$ibase);
$count=ibase_fetch_object($busca);
$total=count($busca);

while($row=ibase_fetch_object($busca)){

    //dentro da query o nome raas.cid10 são banco de dados e tabela
    $sql =mysql_query("insert into raas.cid10 (codigo, descricao) values ('".$row->CD_COD."', '".substr($row->CD_DESCR,5,100)."') ",$mysql);
    $i++;

    $largura=(($i*100)/$total);//calcula andamento da operação em percentual
    $perc=(int)($largura);
    echo "<div style='width:300px; height:20px; background:#fff; border:1px solid #f00; position:absolute; top:55px; left:10px'>
        <div style='width:$largura%; height:20px; background:#f00; position:absolute; top:0; left:0'></div>
    </div>

    <div style='width:100px; height:20px; background:#fff; position:absolute; top:95px; left:155px'>$perc</div>
    ";

}
if($sql){
echo $i."registros importados";
}

?>
```