# Select no Mysql e insert no Firebird

Tags: php, mysql, firebird

Como fazer um "select" no banco de dados Mysql/Mariadb e "insert" dos dados coletados no firebird(interbase).

Comment: Pode começar com [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21858/91)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, agora me deu uma ideia. Mas como seria passar esses dados via webserver?

Comment: Criar um ou consumir?

Comment: Na verdade os dois. Criar passando os dados do mysql e consumir salvando no Firebird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, você deve conectar nos dois bancos de dados simultaneamente.

Após executar o SELECT no MySQL você terá uma variável `array` ou `object` contendo as informações, feito isso você conecta no FireBird e monta o INSERT utilizando esta variável.

Comment: Acabei usando um webservice para isso, e faz exatamente o que descreveu, obrigado.